# Find string under the caret in Eclipse default editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, editor, eclipse-rcp

I wanna get string under the caret position **programmatically** in Eclipse.

I've already seen this link: [How to get cursor position in an eclipse TextEditor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6827797/how-to-get-cursor-position-in-an-eclipse-texteditor)
but in this link, the word(which i want to get) has to selected. In my question it has not to be selected. 
For example source code is:

```
class HelloWorld 
{ 
   public static void main(String args[]) 
   { 
       System.out.println("Hello, World"); 
   } 
}
```

Imagine the caret is in the middle of the any word in this method. I used `|` symbol instead of a caret to explain myself.

```
Syst|em.out.println("Hello, World");
```

For this example i have to get the "System" word.

Is there any way to get this?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the `StyledText` control used by a text editor part using:

```java
StyledText styledText = (StyledText)editorPart.getAdapter(Control.class);
```

`StyledText` has a `getCaretOffset` method:

```java
int offset = styledText.getCaretOffset();
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately, this it not what i want actually. It seems i couldn't explain myself correctly. I have edited question, would you look at it again?

Comment: Well what do mean by 'word'? What if the caret is in the "Hello, World" string? If you want the current programming language element, that is a much more complex question.

Comment: İf caret is in somewhere in Hello, World i have to get 'Hello' or 'World' again. Actually i wanna find the word( i mean any word some string or statement, anything in the source code) to find the caret is in any method or not. When i find the caret in a method, i want to invoke an action. I did it in Visual Studio for my plugins one of action. Now, i want to add that action to my Eclipse plugin.